# Unable to use remove() method with lists in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to code a simple problem which goes as follows:

> This week there will be an important meeting of your entire department. You clearly remember your boss telling you about it. The only thing you forgot is the day of the week when the meeting will take place.
>
> You asked six of your colleagues about the meeting. None of them knew the day when it will take place, but each of them remembered one day when it will not take place. The days they remembered were distinct. For a clever programmer like you, this was enough to determine the day of the meeting.

Now I have created two arrays for it, one containig all the weekdays and one containing all the days where the meeting would not take place and then created two lists from them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] notOnThisDay={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",   "Thursday", "Friday"};
    String[] weekdays={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    List<String> list1=Arrays.asList(weekdays);
    List<String> list2=Arrays.asList(notOnThisDay);
    Iterator<String> iter=list1.iterator();
    
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        if(list2.contains(iter.next())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    for(String x:list1) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

My strategy was to traverse through the weekdays list and if I find any day which is also present in the `notonThisDay` list, then I remove it. As such I am left with the day on which the meeting is to take place, but there seems to be something wrong with the `iter.remove()` method.

Please point out the error. And give me advice if my algorithm is good. I accept suggestions for a better algorithm if any.

Comment: What do you mean by "something is wrong with the `iter.remove()` method"? Does it do something unexpected? If so, what is it doing and what do you *expect* it to do? Does it throw an exception? If so, what exception is it?

Comment: It gives the following exception : : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source) at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source) at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(Unknown Source) at WhichDay.main(WhichDay.java:20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `Arrays.asList()` returns a list of fixed size.  You're better to use one of the constructors of a known type of list, such as `new ArrayList( ... )` or `new LinkedList( ... )`.

Comment: I didn't knew that Arrays.asList() creates an immutable list. Even if i use the constructors such as new ArrayList() or new LinkedList(), then i would need to populate the list from arrays. Won't it create a problem then ?

Comment: Actually, `Arrays.asList()` returns a **fixed sized** lists.  The list *can* in fact be modified, using `List.set(int, E)`.  The reason that the `remove()` method is not supported is that it would change the size of the list.

Comment: Accepted answer with score of -1. Hmmm, this is worthy of a screenshot :D .

Comment: @CSSS - but you can write something like `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(weekDays))`

Answer (score 2):

Collections have a removeAll() method that would be perfect.

Comment: Ok. So that means i can directly subtract all the common elements between two lists form one list ?

Comment: Yes.  list1.removeAll(list2);

Comment: The following error message pops up : 
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(Unknown Source)
 at WhichDay.main(WhichDay.java:20)

Comment: @CSSS [Collections#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) and [Collections#removeAll]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection) info will give you a better understanding of the code.

Comment: Arrays.asList returns an unmodifiable list.

Answer (score 2):

The lists returned by asList are very limited, and do not support remove at all. Make linked lists and add all the items to em, and read the doc on removing mid- iteration. Or use one of the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have 6 different days that it is NOT on, then there is no way the final list will be >1, as I do not forsee anyone adding more days to a week anytime soon. So you can stop looking after you have found day of the week that is not in the `notOnthisDay` list. Thus use a set `Set` of the days of the week it is not on and do a quick look up:

```
Set notDays = new HashSet(notOnThisDay);
String dayOfMtg = null;
for(String day : weekdays) {
   if(notDays.contains(day) {
      //Store response
      dayOfMtg = day;
      //Stop searching, you've found it.
      break;
   }
}
System.out.println("Meeting is on: "+dayOfMtg);
```

Comment: Actually, I thought of using hashSets before and honestly i felt it would have been better. but then i decided against it, i don't know why! Thanks for the help. I will be using hashsets the next time i encounter such problems.

Comment: Its the faster option when you are check if an item is in a set... There may even be utility functions in Google's common code that looks up and returns a set of items in one set but not in another...

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinkedList` for the List under modification.

```
List<String> list1=new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(weekdays));
```

It will work.
**Iterator.remove() is an optional operation** , not supported by every Iterator or its  Underlying Collection.

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next. The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.
>
> Throws:
> UnsupportedOperationException - if the remove operation is not supported by this Iterator.
> IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you have to be careful removing things from a collection you're iterating over. Perhaps you can find a way to avoid this?

Comment: Generally, using `iterator.remove()` is fair game, though, as long as you're not simultaneously modifying the collection through some other means. Problem here is that `Arrays.asList()` returns an implementation that does not support .remove() (throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: I have seen people using the iter.remove() method like this. But in my case, JVM throws a bunch of exceptions

Comment: Ok, but you *can* iterate over one list and remove from the other.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` creates an unmodifiable list. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. You can't add to it; you can't remove from it. You can't structurally modify the List.

Wrap it in a modifiable list like this:

```
someList.addAll(Arrays.asList(newArray));
```

This will create a little extra garbage, but you will be able to mutate it.

Your code now should be like the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] notOnThisDay={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",   "Thursday", "Friday"};
    String[] weekdays={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    //List<String> list1=Arrays.asList(weekdays);
    //List<String> list2=Arrays.asList(notOnThisDay);

    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(weekdays));
    list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(notOnThisDay));

    Iterator<String> iter=list1.iterator();
    //ListIterator<String> iter = list1.listIterator();  Better to use

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        if(list2.contains(iter.next())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    for(String x:list1) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed size, not immutable. Not the same thing.